# Trying to pass python variables inside sh script

Tags: python, bash

I have an sh script and I'm trying to call a python program inside it through an environmental variable but it's returning an error

Script:

```sh
#!/system/bin/sh
MN_MOVI="--movie_template '<$title ><($year)><$extension>'" 
mnamer test.mp4 "$MN_MOVI"
```

Error:

```
mnamer: error: unrecognized arguments: --movie_template '< ><()><>'
```

Code works fine with

```
mnamer test.mp4 --movie_template '<$title ><($year)><$extension>'
```

Edit --

tripleee linked the correct fix, setting MN_MOVI as an array fixed it

```
MN_MOVI=(--movie_template '<$title ><($year)><$extension>')
mnamer test.mp4 "${MN_MOVI[@]}"
```

Comment: The double quotes cause the content to be evaluated, not just treated as literals. As there are no matching env vars, you end up with empty brackets.

Comment: Did you export your variables?

Comment: try mnamer test.mp4 $MN_MOVI, without double quotes around $MN_MOVI.

Comment: `/system/bin/sh` looks odd, and definitely isn't [tag:bash]

Comment: Needed to set an array, thanks all!